# value of td using jquery but from table inside table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to get td value of element inside td in table with class t2
how can i achieve it??
i tried this but didnt help

```
var test = $(.lv1 tr:nth-child(" + row2 + ")").children("td:last").children(".lv2 tr:last").children("td:last").html();
```

table

```
<listview1>
<itemtemplate>
    <table class="t1">
    <tr class="lv1"><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="lv1"><td colspan="2">
<listview2>
<itemtemplate>
    <table class="t2">
    <tr class="lv2">
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lv2">
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</itemtemplate>
</listview2>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</itemtemplate>
</listview1>
```

Comment: the year 1900 is calling they want there tables for layouting back. On a serious note: it looks like your using tables for layout purposes, which is bad m'kay. Better use `div`s.

Comment: On a even more serious note. You have syntax errors. `$(.lv1 tr:nth-child(" + row2 + ")")` should be `$(".lv1 tr:nth-child(" + row2 + ")")` Note the extra quotes at the start.

Comment: I would try: `$('table.t1 tr.lv1 td table.t2 tr.lv2 td').html()` or `$('.t1 .lv1 td.t2 tr.lv2 td').html();`  Its a lot of selectors though and may be easier to just assign a class to the field you want to get the data from.

Comment: I think you are making this harder than it needs to be. If you know the inner table has that class, you can start the selection from there: `$('.t2 td')` will get you every td inside that table. If you only want the last one, you can append the `.last()` function on the end: `var test = $('.t2 td').last();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, based on your feedback this is what I think you are after. Click on the go button to see it in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/mSHKC/

```
$('#go').click( function() {
    var id = 'foo'; //hardcode id retrieval on button press
    //value of first td of first row in table.t2
    var firstTdFirstRow = $(this).closest('table.t1').find('table.t2 tr:first td:first').html();
    //value of first td of last row in table.t2
    var firstTdLastRow =  $(this).closest('table.t1').find('table.t2 tr:last td:first').html();
});
```

You had this comment, but I'm not sure what it means because I think you made a spelling error.

```
 its selecting right td which i want to but while appenind its getting error
```

Comment: ok u r close but my table has lots of diif tr rows and diff tables so have to specify the tr number with table-t1

Comment: so it gives me value for all td rather than first with this code nysugesion var test = $(this).closest("#ListView1_Table2 tr:nth-child(" + row2 + ") ").find('table.gh tr:first td:first').html();

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something more simple like:

```
$("tr.lv2:eq(0) td").text();
```

To get the first such cell

```
$("tr.lv2:eq(1) td").text();
```

For the second, and so on

Or if you have the index as a variable, you can use the eq **function**:

```
$("tr.lv2").eq(index).find("td").text();
```

Comment: actually this tables are nested listviews so i cant use direct inside class of table i have to choose current tr then inside tr from class of that table

Comment: @AradhanaLohan - Your question isn't clear about what you want. Your code is hard to follow because it is incorrect. Can you please explain in plain english what you want and when?

Comment: @mrtsherman hi can u c the code now its a listview so there parent lsitview will show post and child listview will show comments r u getting me??

Comment: @AradhanaLohan - nope, still don't get it. I can't even tell whether you are traversing between sibling nodes or through the same node. Or why you are using nth-child. The HTML structure helps a lot, but just say plain out what you want. For example, I want the last `td` in table `t1.`

Comment: @mrtsherman i want first td of first and last tr of table .lv2 when m going to click on a textbox from last td of current tr of table lv1

Comment: @mrtsherman i will click on a textbox in td (from tr of .lv1) this will get me the id for post now when i submit the value i want to append it on tr of .lv1 but need to get id of resepective tr's(last/first tr of lv2) first td's value..... current trs(tr of lv1) value gets calculated when textbox is focused that value is row2 , so basicaly i have a table i have tr number then i need to get into that tr then its id then table inside it with id lv2 then its first tr and then first td , i hope u got me now

Comment: now i am getting value its selecting right td which i want to but while appenind its getting error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mrtsherman
I divided two functions td `click` and on textbox `submit` and kept the global variable. Now its working fine

```
var row2;
var test;

$("td").live('click', function () {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    row2 = row + 1;
    test = $(this).closest("#Table1 tr:nth-child(" + row2 + ") ")
                     .find('table.gh tr:first td:first').html();
    // alert(test);
    var test2 = $(this).closest("#Table1 tr:nth-child(" + row2 + ") ")
                     .find('table.gh tr:last');
                });
    $(".commenttext").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
           var test2 = $("#ListView1_Table2 tr:nth-child(" + row2 + ") ")
                         .find('table.gh tr:last');
           test2.after('id:'+ test);
           $(".commenttext").val("");
           $(".commenttext").blur();
           $(".commenttext").height('20px');
        }
    });
```